# Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova Error

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

I recently installed **Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP 3.1** in **Visual Studio 2013 running on Windows 8.1**. I receive the following error when I try to run a standard new Cordova project (in the Android Emulator or Device). The project is named MyCordova01:

OutPut Window show below message:

> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets(103,5):
>   warning : The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation,
>   so it will skip compiling. 1>  GeneratedJavascript= 1> 
>   c:\Users\Vijay.Agarwal\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\BlankCordovaApp1\BlankCordovaApp1>call "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\"\nodevars.bat  1>  Your environment has been set up for
>   using Node.js 0.10.33 (ia32) and npm. 1>  ------ Ensuring correct
>   global installation of package from source package directory:
>   C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO
>   12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\L2TH1VSB.CIX\packages\vs-mda
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

And Error List showing 1 Warning

> Warning   1   The TypeScript Compiler was given no files for compilation,
>   so it will skip compiling.    C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets    103 5   BlankCordovaApp8

Please help me how to resolved this error/problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. the typescript is not an error, it happens when you create a JavaScript cordova project, if you create typescript cordova, this warning will disappear!
2. usually our first try to this kind of build error is to clear the cordova cache via visual studio tools - options - tools for apache cordova, then rebuild the project.

make sure you have internet connection when you do step 2.