# Visual Studio tools for Apache Cordova error with Android Emulator

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I've tried [this helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30511808/visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-error), but I still cannot run a `Hello World!` with *Android Emulator* nor *Device* on Visual Studio!

I constantly get the following meaningless error:

> Error 2   cmd: Command failed with exit code 8

and the output is:

> 1>  ------ npm install of vs-mda@0.1.75 from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3VL3GTZ5.0C3\packages\vs-mda completed.
>
> 1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 8
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

What should I do??

Answer (score 1):

If it work well when using ripple, I think you ran into a known issue with android sdk tool 24.3.2 intalled.

Try follow the instructions mentiond in [this known issus site](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-android.md) to downgrade to version 24.2.

If it is not the case, go to Visual Studio menu Tools->Options-> Project and Solutions -> Select "Diagnostics" in MSBuild project build output verbosity. Share the build log here for furthur investigation.

Answer (score 0):

> Exit code 8 often indicates that at least one of the environment
>   variables that Cordova requires for build has not been added to your
>   path.

I point you to the 2 helpful links below:

[Cannot run Cordova Applications using Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464326/cannot-run-cordova-applications-using-visual-studio-2013)

[An error occurred building visual studio cordova app using multi-device-hybrid-apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668519/an-error-occurred-building-visual-studio-cordova-app-using-multi-device-hybrid-a/23670254#23670254)

I hope that support your issue, let me know..